# Session in Cassandra 3.11.14 in windows not cassandra despite placing the path of the JRE of the jdk8u352-b08 as the value of my JAVA_HOME

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I tried to start up cassandra in my local machine but instead the session failed. Instead I got the ollowing error.

```
C:\Users\Carl>cassandra
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

After doing some research (including reading on past questions posted on stackoverflow), I configured my JAVA_HOME to hold the path for my JRE (C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk8u352-b08\jre) and the system path as "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk8u352-b08\bin" but still ended up with the same error. What is the solution please.

Comment: Is the location of `bin\java` in your `$Path`?  What happens when you type `java -verson`?

Comment: @Aaron I have both java jdk 17 and java jdk 8u352 and I think this has brought a conflict in the paths so I am currently researching on how to use Docker to install cassandra into my local machine. Hope it works.